# ui:repeat using the same client id. c:foreach works fine

Tags: jsf-2, jstl, java-ee-6

I know this may have something to do with the phase each one comes in at.

If I do this.

```
 <ui:repeat id="repeatChart" varStatus="loop" value="#{viewLines.jflotChartList}" var="jflotChart">
                <p:panel>
                    <jflot:chart height="300" width="925" dataModel="#{jflotChart.dataSet}" dataModel2="#{jflotChart.dataSet2}" 
                                 xmin="#{jflotChart.startDateString}" 
                                 xmax="#{jflotChart.endDateString}"
                                 shadeAreaStart ="#{jflotChart.shadeAreaStart}"
                                 shadeAreaEnd ="#{jflotChart.shadeAreaEnd}"
                                 lineMark="#{jflotChart.wrapSpec.benchmark}" yMin="#{jflotChart.yMin}" yMax="#{jflotChart.yMax}"  />
                </p:panel>
                <br />
            </ui:repeat>
```

My code will not work.  Debugging the javascript shows that the same id is generated for every iteration.  I've tried putting loop.index to create an id and that gives me an error saying that id can't be blank.

If I exchange the ui:repeat for a c:forEach it works fine.  Debugging the javascript shows that a new id is created for each iteration.

Here is my backing code(some of it).

```
    <div id="#{cc.id}_flot_placeholder" style="width:#{cc.attrs.width}px;height:#{cc.attrs.height}px;">

        <script type="text/javascript">                 
       //<![CDATA[           
       $(function () {    

var placeholder = $("##{cc.id}_flot_placeholder");
var overviewPlaceholder = $("##{cc.id}_flot_overview");
```

The id needs to be different so the javascript can render to the correct div.  I've tried explicitly defining an id attribute and then passing that as the id in the client code.  Like I said before that doesn't work.  Thanks for any help.

## **EDIT**

Here is my problem.  I can't use the clientId in the div tag because of the colon character obviously.  I have modified it in javascript but how would I get that value to the div.  I can't get the div tag by id because I need to generate the id.  I can't seem to do a document.write() either.  I'm stuck at this point.

```
  <composite:implementation>                

       <div id="#{cc.clientId}_flot_placeholder" style="width:400px;height:400px;">


        <script type="text/javascript">                 
       //<![CDATA[           
       $(function () {  

var clientIdOld = '#{cc.clientId}';  
var clientId = clientIdOld.replace(':', '_');
var placeholder = $('#'+clientId+'_flot_placeholder');
var overviewPlaceholder = $('#'+clientId+'_flot_overview');
```

Comment: Your problem is a bit confusing. Same `id` of *what*? You've it only on `<ui:repeat>`, but this attribute is not supported at all on `<ui:repeat>`. The backing code seems to be a composite component. Is it the `<jflot:chart>`?

Comment: Well in the composite component it takes the the id as a distinct place holder variable.  This place holder(div) is what flot(charting library) uses to display a chart too.  If I use c:forEach the generated id is like jdt:78, jdt:79, etc for each loop.  If i use ui:repeat the id is the same.  jdt:78, jdt:78, jdt:78.  So there is a div with the same id like 5 or 6 times.

Comment: Ah right. I'm afraid it's among one of the many issues on `<ui:repeat>`. http://java.net/jira/secure/QuickSearch.jspa?searchString=ui:repeat Which JSF impl/version?

Comment: Ahhh.  I can't catch a break.  I'm using Mojarra.  I'm at home now so I'm not sure the version at this moment.  I left my laptop at work today.  What should I do?  I can't really using c:forEach because that kills my page performance because it calls the constructor for every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick test on local environment (Mojarra 2.0.4 on Tomcat 7.0.11). Using `#{cc.clientId}` gives you an unique ID back everytime.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <cc:test />
</ui:repeat>
```

with

```
<cc:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}_foo">foo</div>
</cc:implementation>
```

Here's the generated HTML source:

```
<div id="j_idt6:0:j_idt7_foo">foo</div>
<div id="j_idt6:1:j_idt7_foo">foo</div>
<div id="j_idt6:2:j_idt7_foo">foo</div>
```

This should be sufficient for your functional requirement. You might only want to escape the default separator `:` or to replace it by a custom separator since it's a reserved character in CSS selectors.

---

**Update**: so you want to escape it, you should then replace `:` by `\:` and not by `_`.

```
var clientId = clientIdOld.replace(/:/g, '\\:');
```

(the `/:/g` is a regex which ensures that all occurrences will be replaced and the double slash is just to escape the slash itself in JS strings, like as you normally do in Java strings)

Comment: Hey thank you.  That does create a specific id.  I'm having major trouble getting it to work though with my code.  I can't get the modified value into the div tag id.  I've updated my previous post.

Comment: Thanks again.  I figured out the underlining problem.  The replace only replaces the first occurrence of the character.

 var clientId = clientIdOld.replace(/:/g, '\\:');

Source http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/replace-all-occurrences-of-string-using-javascript-replace-function.aspx

This is the code needed to replace all.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed the JS `String#replace()` behaves differently from Java's `String#replace()`. Sorry, I should have known that. Good you figured it out.