# Another "cannot find component" with JSF 2.0 and Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Just saw a lot of questions envolving "update", "@all", "@form", but no one solved a situation here in my application.

I got a custom JSF tag called threadList with:

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <p:commandButton action="#{Bean.action(catId, id)}" icon="ui-icon-weblibrary ui-icon-weblibrary-like" title="Start" update="@form" value="#{Bean.threadName}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

This custom tag is inserted by another custom tag like this:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{Bean.threadList}" var="thread">
   <ui:include src="threadList.xhtml">
      <ui:param name="catId" value="..." />
      <ui:param name="id" value="..." />
   </ui:include>
</ui:repeat>
```

Sometimes this  can be a result of an update in the second taglib and via ajax.

And here's the thing...

- When I set update="@form" in the p:commandButton everything works fine but in my log I see a "Cannot find component with identifier "j_idt70:0:j_idt82" in view.";
- When I set update=":@form" or update=":form" the "Cannot find component with identifier "j_idt70:0:j_idt82" in view." disappears, but the event doesn't update anything (even if the action runs with success);
- Finally, when I give form and panelGroup an id and try update=":formId:panelId" or update=":@formId:panelId" or update=":formId" the message "Cannot find component with identifier "j_idt70:0:j_idt82" in view." appears and nothing is uptade.

The curious is that there's no  in browser's source code. So, I don't know if this "ghost" j_idt70 is corrupting all the ids and update commands.

I tried all the things I learned in old questions in stack overflow before asking you again about this.

Thanks a lot for reading and the attention.

Comment: What JSF impl/version and PF version?

Comment: That "ghost" id is an autogenerated id from a component. Try to add IDs to all your components so when the error message is printed it will tell you the component id you're looking for. Also, if your custom component has a form, remember than the <ui:repeat> will print N forms inside your xhtml page, and the commandButton scope will be only that form (at least with your actual design). If you're using JSF 2, maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5558249/1065197) can help you.

Comment: @BalusC, I'm using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.0.1.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I read the link but I'm afraid we can't change it from a managed bean to a composite component. Not now, maybe in the future.

Comment: "JSF 2.0" is a spec version, not a impl name nor version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code given so far works just fine for me on Mojarra 2.1.9 and PrimeFaces 3.3.

If you upgrade to the latest versions as well, then your problem should most likely be solved.

Comment: I see. I'm using Mojarra 2.1.1 but it's because Netbeans configures it. I can download a new jsf-impl.jar and replace its jar but I wonder if there's a way to upgrade it through Netbeans IDE.

Comment: That's a rather old version, over 1 year old already. Sorry, I do not use Netbeans, so I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: No problem @BalusC you helped me a lot. I will try to update Mojarra and Primefaces and then I'll come back to tell if it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just updated Mojarra and PrimeFaces and all worked! Thanks a lot everyone.